# Blank page with guzzle http

Tags: php, guzzle

I am new to guzzle and I'm testing its api, when I want to run the sample code in guzzle site, a blank page was shown in the browser. What is the problem?
Thanks.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
try {
    $client = new Client();
    $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org');
    $response = $client->send($request, [
        'timeout'  => 30,
    ]);
    echo $response->getBody();
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    echo $e->getRequest();
    if ($e->hasResponse()) {
        echo $e->getResponse();
   }}
```

Comment: Tried it. works. So must be your environment. Did you used composer to install guzzle as dependency?

Comment: Yes, I used composer to install guzzle with command:`composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0`. I work on windows 8.1 and install vagrant with box `hashicorp/precise64` (`ubuntu 12.04`), actually I work in virtual machine.May be this information helps.

Comment: your codes work perfectly. did your php version is 5.5+ ?

Comment: Yes, My php version is 5.5.27.I don't know what was the problem but after reload vagrant the prob fixed. Thank you